# How do i get my repeater results to appear line by line

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater, code-behind

```
<p runat="server" id="pServices">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptServices" OnItemDataBound="rptServices_OnItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService"></asp:Label>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</p>
```

And in the code behind I have

```
private void updatePageWithUserData(User UserProfile)
{
    this.pProfile.InnerText = UserProfile.About;
    rptServices.DataSource = UserProfile.Services;
    rptServices.DataBind();
}

protected void rptServices_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Service serviceItem = (Service)e.Item.DataItem;
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblService")).Text = (serviceItem.ServiceName);

    }
}
```

But the result I get is like this:

`Software Development Web Development`

Instead I want it to appear as:

`Software Development
Web Development`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in WebForms, all of your output is HTML, and HTML as a language does not care about spaces or line breaks.

So, if you view source on that HTML you will see something like this:

```
   <span>Software Development</span>
   <span>Web Development</span>
```

Now, since HTML does not care about the fact that there is a line break in the file, they run together and you see:

Software Development Web Development

So, in order to get the space, you need to indicate that space in a way that HTML understands. There are a few ways of doing that, but I'll suggest three for you here:

1. You can use the <br/> tag, which indicates that a line break should be visually displayed. If you were to go this route, your repeater's item template would look like this:

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService"></asp:Label><br/>
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```
2. SPAN tags are an HTML tag called an inline element, because it does not care about line spacing. If you used a DIV tag or a P tag to wrap your label in, those tags are block elements and do respect spacing, so your item template would look like this:

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <div><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService"></asp:Label></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```
3. You can also make an inline element act like a block element with CSS. By applying a classname to the label and then using CSS to style it, you could get the same result. That would look like this:

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService" CssClass="myStyle"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```

and then the css:

```
   .mystyle { display: block; }
```

That gives you a few different ways to solve the problem and helps explain why your code wasn't working.

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for that, you broke it down as nice as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your output in a div element.

```
  <ItemTemplate>
        <div>    
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblService"></asp:Label>
        </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```