# How to get control of checkbox in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new on this site . I need a help in asp.net C#. In my example, i have  a data-list control,i which i display some record of books like-Book Title, Book Author,Publisher and an image of book.So when i buy one or two books from these records then i select a check-box.After selecting check-boxes,i click on a button through which i get  the information about that selected records in repeater.So my problem is that, when i click on button then how i get the control for selected check-box and information is display in the repeater??

Thank You

HD

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please spare a minute to read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to get a good response from readers, you need to provide more information about your problem, code excerpt would be a good start..

Comment: @YuliamChandra can u please help me to solve this problem. i edit this question hope u get my point.

Comment: could you please put code excerpt of your repeater and the checkboxes that you have in the aspx page just like this [question example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945788/how-do-i-get-my-repeater-results-to-appear-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete sample of how to use `Repeater` with checkboxes.
Item ID is stored in a hidden field for additional information when checking user selection.

This sample may not match your code since you didn't provide any examples.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Repeater Example</title>
    <script language="C#" runat="server">

        public class PositionData
        {
            private int id;
            private string name;
            private string _data;
            private bool selected;

            public PositionData(int id, string name, string data)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this._data = data;
            }

            public int Id
            {
                get { return id; }
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
            }

            public string data
            {
                get { return _data; }
            }

            public bool Selected
            {
                get { return selected; }
            }
        }


        void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

                values.Add(new PositionData(1, "Prod1", "Info1"));
                values.Add(new PositionData(2, "Prod2", "Info1"));
                values.Add(new PositionData(3, "Prod3", "Info1"));

                Repeater1.DataSource = values;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                foreach (RepeaterItem i in Repeater1.Items)
                {
                    //Retrieve the state of the CheckBox
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("selectUser");
                    HtmlInputHidden info = (HtmlInputHidden)i.FindControl("fieldName");
                    String itemInfo = info.Value;
                    if (cb.Checked)
                    {
                        // do whatever you want with selected item
                        // having it's ID
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        private void Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var myHidden = (HtmlInputHidden)e.Item.FindControl("fieldName");
                myHidden.Value = ((PositionData)e.Item.DataItem).Id.ToString();
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Repeater Example</h3>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <b>Repeater1:</b>
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_OnItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Select this one</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Data</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="selectUser" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "data") %>
                    <input id="fieldName" runat="server" type="hidden" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <br />
    <button id="submitButton" runat="server">Submit!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```